# How to fliter based on the embeded collection field in mongo db

Tags: mongodb, filter

I have a collection like the one below

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("573eb77bf3465096ddb1e873"), 
    "id" : 1, 
    "name" : "siva", 
    "email" : "sivateja@gmail.com", 
    "address" : [ 
        { "street" : "balajinager", "district" : "nellore", "state" : "A.p" }, 
        [ { "street" : "balajinager", "district" : "nellore", "state" : "A.p" } ] 
    ] 
}
```

I want to filter the records based on the `city`, which is inside the `address` array, how can we do that in mongo db?

Comment: check for `$elemMatch`
https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.find/#query-an-array-of-documents

Comment: thank you verymuch this solves my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

district also fine?

```
{address:{$elemMatch:{district:"nellore"}}}
```

see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/